# Constraints messing up frame size

Tags: ios, layout, swift, ios8

I use the following line of code to set the size of a button:

```
self.toolsButton.frame.size = CGSizeMake(190, 40)
```

All is fine, until I add the following layout constraint:

```
var constrainToCenter = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolsButton, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

self.view.addConstraint(constrainToCenter)
```

As I understand it, this constraint code horizontally centers the button with the view, but why would that have an effect on the frame size? How can I maintain the frame size while also having the constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a height and a width constraint to enforce the size of the button.

If you are using constraints, it's best if your constraints completely define the size and position of the element.
When you add constraints for just one attribute, it can conflict with the default system constraints.

---

Edit - some more information:

If you create the view in code, the view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints attribute should default to YES.

This means that the system will automatically add constraints to it. And probably they conflict with the constraint you added manually.

So the best solution here, I think, is to set

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO
```

and then add 4 constraints manually:

- horizontal position
- vertical position
- height
- width

When you don't need to create any specific constraints, just leave that option to YES, the system will create constraints to enforce the frame you set and often that will be enough.

Comment: So essentially constraints overrule other changes made to relevant attributes, even if the constraint doesn't directly deal with that attribute?

Comment: I edited the answer with some better information to explain it.